# Is it possible to type hint a string that has numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting

**Is it possible to annotate a string that can be properly converted to an int?**

Something like this...

```
def foo(arg: str[int]): # which of course does not work
    ...
```

Which is the equivalent of successfully calling `int(arg)`.

I could have sworn there was a way to validate types of strings via type hinting in Pycharm (and perhaps it was a non-PEP feature) but I can't for the life of me figure out how or why I think this feature exists.

Comment: This really doesn't make sense to me, this isn't a type at all, and isn't really something that can be checked statically, unless you create such a type.

Comment: Logically I know this; That said I keep thinking there is something similar to how `List[str]` works.  Almost like a type-inside-a-type.  Maybe I dreamt it...

Comment: Nope, because `'1'` is still a `str`. A `str` isn't really a collection anyway, so it doesn't make sense to parametrize (if it *is* a collection, then it is a collection of unicode code points). Anyway, I'm fairly certain this isn't built-in anywhere

Comment: If you have a `str` which represents an `int`, and you use its numerical property, why not just pass the `int` in the first place?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga technically, in some languages a `str` is represented as `char[]`, though obviously that doesn't apply to Python.

Comment: @CalvinGodfrey well sure, but thankfully, we aren't working with C-strings. In python, there are `bytes` objects and `str` objects. Both are *sequences* and both are technically containers, but they are odd containers, they contain instances of themselves. Underneath the hood, `bytes` objects have an array of bytes, (i.e. chars) and `str` objects have an array of unicode code points. But that isn't really relevant to the *Python typing* system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible because you are not dealing with *types* here.

You are trying to make assertions about the contents of individual strings, so you are making assertions about *instances*. That's not something that type hinting can solve for you.